# Wampserver 2.2 on Windows 7 Orange Icon Nothing in error files

Tags: wamp, wampserver

Ok. So I've installed Wampserver 2.2 on my WIndows 7 computer....on starting wamp, the icon goes from red to orange and just stays orange. I can't run any php files. I hover over it and all it says is that the server is offline.  Both apache and php error files are empty. I've tried running as administrator and even changed the compatibility to Windows XP sp2.  I do not  have skype on my computer.  I do have google talk.  Any ideas on what to do to get wamp running?

Answer (score 0):

Look in Apache's httpd.conf file and see what port it wants to use, then see if any other programs are using the same port.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this for hours on end on different machines. Often one solution did not work on the next machine. This is what I, by trial and error, found out worked like a charm every time.

Installed WAMP on win7 POS

Add MSVCR100.dll to System32
Install VB 2008
Install WAMP
Disable World wide web publishing service in Services
Start WAMP as administrator.
Finished. No need to edit httpd.conf, no need to edit hosts-file and no need to disable IIS.

A total install of WAMP following these steps take well under ten minutes. Hope it does the trick for you as well.

Comment: MSVCR100.dll is a component of Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable and the proper way to install it into the system is by installing the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable downloaded from Microsoft. Putting DLL files manually into system folders creates DLL hell and should always be avoided.